# I can't access my Postgres server remotely

Tags: networking, postgresql

I have a Postgres db running on a linux server in my home. I want to be able to access it from my public IP address remotely but it seems not to be working.

I have `listen_address = "*"` set in my conf as well as

```
host    all             all             0.0.0.0/0               scram-sha-256
host    all             all             ::/0                    scram-sha-256
```

set in the pg_hba.conf. I have port 5432 forwarded in my router and I know for a fact it works. I use dbeaver and when I run the test connection with my public IP it says that the connection is successful.

[image]

Which makes me think everything should be fine. However, when I try to open the database I get a connection timeout.

[image]

I disabled ufw just to check if that was the issue and I got the same thing. I tried connecting to it locally using the IP address of the server rather than my public IP and it works perfectly fine with the server IP address on my local network.

I even tried changing the port from 5432 to 8080 to see if that might have been an issue and I still get the same result.

I also tried hosting a simple website on port 8080 using nginx and I can see that in my browser using my public IP just fine so I can't think of anything that would be blocking any ports.

Is there something in my postgres config that I'm missing or anything because I'm totally stumped here.

Comment: are all these tests run from within your home network?

Comment: Have you reviewed the PostgreSQL server logs located in the PostgreSQL data directory (usually /var/log/postgresql/) for any error messages or warnings. These logs can provide valuable information about connection issues.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that postgresql is listening on the LAN address that your router is forwarding packets to.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely your PostgreSQL instance at home is running behind some kind of NAT from your router.

You will need to setup port forwarding in your router to forward the port 5432 to your server behind your router. Also if you do not have a static ip address you will need a dynamic dns service to map a domain name to your upstream ip address.

The specific steps depend on your setup in use.